# Returning a string with one line per index

Tags: c#, arrays, string, textbox, multiline

Multi-line, textBox1.Text =

```
RGYR
RGGB
RGRG
RYBG
RYYB
GBRY
RYBG
```

I want the game to read each line one at a time, however;

```
Color[] colourset = newSequence(textBox1.Text.Length);
```

is reading the string as a whole, without anticipating the line break at every 4th character and it's messing everything up.

How can I make it read one line per index in a multi-line textbox?

Code for context:

```
private Color[] sequence;
//Declare dictionary
private Dictionary<char,Color>  stringTocolor = new Dictionary<char,Color>();

public SimonSays ()
{
    //add content to Dictionary
    stringTocolor.Add('R', Color.Red);
    stringTocolor.Add('G', Color.Green);
    stringTocolor.Add('B', Color.Blue);
    stringTocolor.Add('Y', Color.Yellow);

    Color[] colourset = newSequence(textBox1.Text.Length); //This may be the problem? Reading entire string length instead of just one line at a time??
}

public Color[] newSequence(int length)
{
    Color[] array = new Color[length];
    //check dictionary has the char key or not
    for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (stringTocolor.ContainsKey(textBox1.Text[i]))
        {
             array[i] = stringTocolor[textBox1.Text[i]];
        }
        //give alert if wrong key
        else
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Wrong Colour input at index " + i + " of textbox string!");
        }
    }
    this.sequence = array;
    return array;
}
public void newSequence (Color [] sequence)
    {
    this.sequence= //read next line of string
    }
```

Comment: Figure out what the line break character is and String.Split? Seems like you need to do that first.

Answer (score 1):

You can index via the [Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < textBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
      Color[] colourset = newSequence(textBox1.Lines[i].Length);
```

Comment: Thanks for the message! I get 'wrong color input at index 4 & 5'

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it read one line per index in a multi-line textbox?

You can split your string based on `EnvironMent.NewLine` and then take the required item using index in the loop.

Try This:

```
var lines = textBox1.Text.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine},
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it, turns out it was just this.

```
Color[] colourset = newSequence(textBox1.Lines[0].Length);
```